# fragmnet add MainActivity

Tags: java, android-fragment

Не получается добавить Fragment в MainActivity
Помогите плез

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас FragmentMy является FragmentActivity. 
а нужно Fragment.
Замените

```
class FragmentMy extends Fragment
```

Comment: Спасибо,

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

ругается на this

Comment: @Kirill, замените this на `getContext()`

Comment: спасибо , все правильно только приложение вылетает, fragment в activity серый нормально?

Comment: @Kirill не видя ваш код и логи ошибок - очень трудно вам помочь

Comment: @Kirill, покажите код текстом в вопросе. И логи ошибки. И лучше в отдельном вопросе, пометив этот ответ верным. Гадая, можно лишь предположить, что у вас NPE, т.к. вы не указали разметку в `onCreateView` методе фрагмента.